# Reciprocal Altitude Theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles

If $ABC$ is a triangle such that $D  \in (BC) $ ,  $AD^2 =BD \cdot CD$ and $AD= \frac{AB \cdot AC}{BC} $ show that $ABC$ is a right triangle. I tried to solve it with Stewart Theorem but the calculus are not very frendly  .

Comment: It will likely help your Readers to see more details of where you stopped in your attempt to solve this, to avoid repeating unnecessary background if for no other reason.  The notation is a bit cryptic, so if I understand correctly that $D$ is a point in the interior of the line segment $\overline{BC}$, then I would state it fully in the body of the Question.

Comment: I  tried to find BD and CD  using Stewart Th  but the calculus.... I haven't another idea ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notation: $AB=c$, $AC=b$, $BC=a$ , $AD=d ,CD=x,BD=a-x $ .
We can write the second condition as :

$\frac{d}{c}= \frac{b}{a} \Rightarrow \frac{\sin B}{\sin \angle ADB} = \frac{\sin B}{\sin A } \Rightarrow \angle ADB = A $ or $\angle ADB= \pi-A$

That means that one of triangles ABD or ADC is similar to triangle ABC.

Wlog, let $\triangle ABD \sim \triangle ABC$ ($\angle ADB=\angle A)$

From there we get following ratio:

$ \frac{x}{c}=\frac{c}{a}  \Rightarrow ax=c^2 $

$d^2=x(a-x)=ax-x^2=c^2-x^2 \Rightarrow x^2+d^2=c^2 \Rightarrow \angle ADB= 90^\circ = \angle A$

So the triangle ABC is right triangle with $A=90^\circ$